# Rails 6.1 upgrade: undefined method `assert_nothing_raised'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm running into this error when upgrading from Rails 6.0.3 to 6.1:

```rb
  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `assert_nothing_raised' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::EmailJob:0x00005572d8a00758>
    Did you mean?  assert_raises
```

This happens every time a test calls `perform_enqueued_jobs`.
I'm using RSpec 3.9.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently `assert_nothing_raised` is a helper method defined by ActiveSupport. I was able to solve this issue by explicitly including the helper in `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(ActiveSupport::Testing::Assertions)
  # ...
```